# Can I increase the processing speed by adding more cpus to operators in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

In `airflow.cfg` there is a section called `[operators]`, where `default_cpus` was set to `1` and `default_ram` and `default_disk` were both set to `512`.

I would like to understand whether will I get improvements in processing speed if I increase these parameters or not.

Comment: Perhaps you can get some interesting response if you could also tell what executor are you using.

Comment: Sorry to bother, if you found the answer useful, could you please upvote it? I'm trying to gather some score to be able to perform some cleanup on the [apache-airflow] tag. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, reputation under 15, fairly new to stack overflow

Comment: Perhaps now you can try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I took a look at the sources and these settings are available to all operators, but they are never used, neither by operators nor by any executor.

So I went a little bit back into history and had a look at [the commit that introduced those settings](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/1669/commits/2c37d26e69248ac7898d013ab341eecf43888c0a) and they are, [quoting the JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-341) that lead to that PR:

> optional resource requirements for use with resource managers such as yarn and mesos

The Mesos executor, however, is a community contribution that does not leverage this properties and just [assigns the same amount of resources to every task](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/contrib/executors/mesos_executor.py#L110-L161), and the YARN executor is not there yet AFAIK (as of version 1.9).

I once had a discussion with the Airflow team to understand if there was a way to assign resources on a per task basis using the Mesos executor and they replied me with [their strategy to assign resources to tasks using the Celery executor](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/1cb1e2d336212f2ac3ad5eb698ca5aedde136df0f398acde8cabc3ca@%3Cdev.airflow.apache.org%3E), in case it may be of help to you to understand how to manage resources.

Regarding the core question that you are asking in a more general sense, the kind of throughput that you can get out of a task in relation with the resources it gets assigned, depends a lot on the task itself: of course a very compute-intensive task that can leverage multiple processors will see speed bumps if you assign it multiple cores, while an I/O intensive task (like copying data between different systems) will probably not see much improvement.

Comment: so can i assume that for `LocalExecutor`, `default_cpus` settings is ignored? In that case **max no of tasks running at any moment** (assuming only 1 `DAG` is running) should be entirely dependent on `dag_concurrency`. Actually my `scheduler` is not running more than 7-8 tasks at a time so i thought maybe it had something to do with `cpus`. I'm using `Airflow` as **pure scheduler** (all tasks run on *remote systems* over `SSH` or something similar), so i always thought in this setting *sky would be the limit* to how many concurrent tasks can be run. (Its a 4 vCore box `r4.xlarge` on `EMR`)

Comment: I would not assume that, especially considering that this reply is not very fresh. My suggestion is to go have a look at the code, if the documentation is not clear in this regard.