# How to set request_cpu globally for airflow worker pods using the kubernetes executor?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I'm trying to set the `request_cpu` parameter in the Kubernetes executor for Airflow but haven't been able to find where I can do that. In the [default airflow config](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg) I found `default_cpus` but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48223083/6733371) there is nowhere that that is used, and nowhere else in the Kubernetes section could I find a reference to the CPU request.

How can I set the `request_cpu` parameter in the Airflow Kubernetes executor?

EDIT: 
Ideally, what I would like to be able to do is set this as a global default rather than on a per-operator basis, even though in general I think that it does make more sense to set it per-operator/task

Comment: I _think_ this should now also be possible with the pod template file feature

Answer (score 4):

You can set this `executor_config` at task level for KubernetesExecutor as follows.

```py
    exmaple_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="exmaple_task",
        python_callable=print_stuff,
        executor_config={
            "KubernetesExecutor": {"request_cpu": "1",
                                   "request_memory": "128Mi",
                                   "limit_memory": "128Mi"}}
    )
```

You can define the following in `executor_config` :

- image
- image_pull_policy
- request_memory
- request_cpu
- limit_memory
- limit_cpu
- limit_gpu
- node_selectors
- affinity
- tolerations
- annotations
- volumes
- volume_mounts
- volume_mounts

**Doc**: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.9/_api/airflow/contrib/executors/kubernetes_executor/index.html#airflow.contrib.executors.kubernetes_executor.KubernetesExecutorConfig

Comment: Can a default be set globally, though?

Comment: You can set it in default_args for the DAG, so you don't need to duplicate per task. But to set it globally you can enforce policy using pod_mutation_hook (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/kubernetes.html#pod-mutation-hook)

Comment: Hmm. It's unfortunate that there's not an easier way to do that. Thanks for the point to the pod_mutation_hook, I'll check that out

Comment: @kaxil, Where should the pod_mutation_hook function defined. Is it defined for each DAG file? I have tried to add a test annotation for KubernetesExecutor, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The pod_mutation_hook should be defined in `airflow_local_settings.py` file and this file should be on the PYTHONPATH. So it can stay in `$AIRFLOW_HOME/configs/airflow_local_settings.py`

Comment: Hi @kaxil, I have tried to create a pod_mutation_hook function in airflow_local_settings.py and put it under $AIRFLOW_HOME/configs/airflow_local_settings.py, wich which set the annotation pod.annotations['airflow.apache.org/launched-by'] = 'Tests'. However, this annotation is not picked up by KubernetesExecututor Pod. I have no idea, Do you have a good example code of pod_mutation_hook?

Comment: @fuyi here is an example: https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-chart/blob/master/templates/configmap.yaml#L131-L152

Comment: I tried this on airflow v2.4.1 but got `[2022-11-23, 11:18:36 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:117} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/kubernetes/pod_generator.py:176 RemovedInAirflow3Warning: Using a dictionary for the executor_config is deprecated and will soon be removed.please use a `kubernetes.client.models.V1Pod` class with a "pod_override" key instead.`

Does anyone know an example of the new approach it wants?